# scons dependency problems in a hierarchical build with variant dirs

Tags: scons

Im new to scons and am having problems with scons dependancies 
in a hierarchichal build with a variant directory.

Im able to reproduce the problem in a reduced environment that consists of
2 subdirs under the SConscript directory (moduleA and moduleB) as follows:

```
.
|-- SConstruct
|-- file.conf
|-- moduleA
|   |-- SConscript
|   `-- conf2cc
`-- moduleB
    |-- SConscript
    `-- fileB.cc
```

Here is the flow of what needs to be done:

1. moduleA executes a shell script: conf2cc, input: $projRootDir/file.conf, output: moduleA/$variantDir/source.cc
2. moduleA compiles source.cc and creates moduleA/$variantDir/libmoduleA.a
3. moduleB needs to copy moduleA/$variantDir/source.cc to moduleB/source.cc
4. moduleB needs to compile moduleB/source.cc and moduleB/fileB.cc into its
   library libmoduleB.a

Its entirely possible that Im doing several things wrong here. For example, I know
Im not using $TARGET/$SOURCE in moduleA Command(), but thats on purpose, since the
script needs the absolute path names, and scons doesnt remove the leading '#'

The problem I have is the Command() builder in moduleB (step 3 above) never executes.

Here are the SConstruct and SConscript files:

Sconstruct

```
import os

env = Environment()
env['variantDir'] = 'linux'  # for this example, just make variantDir = linux
modules = ['moduleA', 'moduleB']

for dir in modules:
    SConscript(
        os.path.join(dir, 'SConscript'),
        variant_dir = os.path.join(dir, env['variantDir']),
        exports = ['env'],
        duplicate = 0)
```

moduleA/Sconscript

```
import os

Import('env')

scriptInput   = '#file.conf'
sourceFile    = os.path.join('#moduleA', env['variantDir'],  'source.cc')
conf2ccScript = File('#moduleA/conf2cc').abspath

# The script needs abspaths for input and output, not the scons '#' prepended
# the script syntax is: script <inputFile> <outputFile>
cmd = '%s %s %s' % (conf2ccScript, File(scriptInput).abspath, File(sourceFile).abspath)

# Generate source.cc file based on file.conf
conf2ccNode = env.Command(target = sourceFile,
                          source = scriptInput,
                          action = cmd)

libNode = env.Library(target = 'moduleA', source = sourceFile)
env.Depends(libNode, conf2ccNode)
```

moduleB/Sconscript

```
import os

Import('env')

sourceFiles = ['fileB.cc', 'source.cc']

# Get the source.cc file
externalSourceFile  = os.path.join('#moduleA', env['variantDir'], 'source.cc')
sourceTarget        = os.path.join('#moduleB', 'source.cc')

cmdNode = env.Command(target = sourceTarget,
                      source = externalSourceFile,
                      action = Copy('$TARGET', '$SOURCE'))

libNode = env.Library(target = 'moduleB', source = sourceFiles)
env.Depends(libNode, cmdNode)
```

Here is the output when I execute scons:

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Brady

```
notroot@ubuntu:~/projects/sconsTest/sconsTestHierDeps$ scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
/home/notroot/projects/sconsTest/sconsTestHierDeps/moduleA/conf2cc /home/notroot/projects/sconsTest/sconsTestHierDeps/file.conf /home/notroot/projects/sconsTest/sconsTestHierDeps/moduleA/linux/source.cc
g++ -o moduleA/linux/source.o -c moduleA/linux/source.cc
ar rc moduleA/linux/libmoduleA.a moduleA/linux/source.o
ranlib moduleA/linux/libmoduleA.a
g++ -o moduleB/linux/fileB.o -c moduleB/fileB.cc
scons: *** [moduleB/linux/source.o] Source `moduleB/source.cc' not found, needed by target `moduleB/linux/source.o'.
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest problem in incorrect dependency what you use and filenames.

May be problem in variant_dir and source files for moduleB, you use Command to generate #/moduleB/source.cc, but in sourceFiles you have 'source.cc'.

So, one of ways to help you may be correct moduleB SConscript :

```
# Get the source.cc file
externalSourceFile  = os.path.join('#moduleA', env['variantDir'], 'source.cc')
sourceTarget        = os.path.join('#moduleB', 'source.cc')

sourceFiles = ['fileB.cc', sourceTarget]

cmdNode = env.Command(target = sourceTarget,
                      source = externalSourceFile,
                      action = Copy('$TARGET', '$SOURCE'))

libNode = env.Library(target = 'moduleB', source = sourceFiles)
```

And try to use Command like source file. instead filename. It's looks more correct.
moduleA :

```
conf2ccNode = env.Command(target = sourceFile,
                          source = scriptInput,
                          action = cmd)
libNode = env.Library(target = 'moduleA', source = conf2ccNode)
```

moduleB:

```
cmdNode = env.Command(target = sourceTarget,
                      source = externalSourceFile,
                      action = Copy('$TARGET', '$SOURCE'))

libNode = env.Library(target = 'moduleB', source = ['fileB.cc', cmdNode])
```

Comment: Excellent! That works as expected. I like that SCons figures out the implicit dependencies instead of having to list them explicitly with the Depends() function. Thanks alot!

Comment: One caveat, though: the object file for moduleB/source.cc is placed in moduleB and not in the variant_dir for moduleB, whereas fileB.o is indeed placed in the variant_dir. Why is that? How can I get source.o to be placed in the variant_dir?

Comment: I figured it out by specifying the moduleB source.cc file as follows:
`sourceTarget = os.path.join('#moduleB', env['variantDir'], 'source.cc')` so that now the source.cc and source.o files are placed in the variant_dir.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem, but I dont really understand why it works.

If I add a call to env.Default() with the targets I need built, then it works. So the SConscript files would then look like this:

moduleA/Sconscript

```
import os

Import('env')

scriptInput   = '#file.conf'
sourceFile    = os.path.join('#moduleA', env['variantDir'],  'source.cc')
conf2ccScript = File('#moduleA/conf2cc').abspath

# The script needs abspaths for input and output, not the scons '#' prepended
# the script syntax is: script <inputFile> <outputFile>
cmd = '%s %s %s' % (conf2ccScript, File(scriptInput).abspath, File(sourceFile).abspath)

# Generate source.cc file based on file.conf
conf2ccNode = env.Command(target = sourceFile,
                          source = scriptInput,
                          action = cmd)

libNode = env.Library(target = 'moduleA', source = sourceFile)
env.Depends(libNode, conf2ccNode)
env.Default([conf2ccNode, libNode])
```

moduleB/Sconscript

```
import os

Import('env')

sourceFiles = ['fileB.cc', 'source.cc']

# Get the source.cc file
externalSourceFile  = os.path.join('#moduleA', env['variantDir'], 'source.cc')
sourceTarget        = os.path.join('#moduleB', 'source.cc')

cmdNode = env.Command(target = sourceTarget,
                      source = externalSourceFile,
                      action = Copy('$TARGET', '$SOURCE'))

libNode = env.Library(target = 'moduleB', source = sourceFiles)
env.Depends(libNode, cmdNode)
env.Default(cmdNode, libNode)
```

So that leads to the question: If I dont specify Default() targets and there is more than one target, how does scons know which one to build?

Also, I still dont understand why scons doesnt resolve the dependancy in moduleB/SConscript that libNode has on the cmdNode.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
def CreateLibrary(env, name, sources, shared=True):

    def GetObjectFile(sourceFileName):

        def GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path):
            return os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0]

        def IsFileNameExist(newFileName):
            return fileNames.count(newFileName) > 0

        sourceAbsPath = os.path.abspath(sourceFileName)
        fileNameWithoutExtension = GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sourceAbsPath)
        destFileName = fileNameWithoutExtension
        attemptNumber = 0
        while IsFileNameExist(destFileName):
            attemptNumber += 1
            destFileName = fileNameWithoutExtension + str(attemptNumber)
        fileNames.append(destFileName)
        destFilePath = os.path.join(compilationDirRoot, destFileName)
        if shared:
            return env.SharedObject(destFilePath, sourceAbsPath)
        else:
            return env.StaticObject(destFilePath, sourceAbsPath)

    objFiles = []
    fileNames = []
    compilationDirRoot = Dir('.').abspath
    for src in sources:
        if isinstance(src,str):
            objFiles.append(GetObjectFile(src))
        elif isinstance(src, SCons.Node.FS.File):
            objFiles.append(GetObjectFile(SCons.Node.FS.File.rstr(src)))
        else:
            for f in src:
                objFiles.append(GetObjectFile(str(f)))
    if shared:
        return env.SharedLibrary(name, objFiles, no_import_lib=True)
    else:
        return env.StaticLibrary(name, objFiles)
```

Example of use:

```
theora = CreateLibrary(env, 'theora', sources)
```